# Detect an Element in event bubbles

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, jquery-events, event-bubbling

I have this html code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="parent">
     <!-- P Element Completely On Parent -->
     
     <p style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Hello</p>
   
     </div>
   ........
</div>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
 
  if ( e.target == document.querySelector(".parent") ) {
    
     alert(" It Worked!!! ")
  
  }

}, 
true // <--- bubbling
)
```

- **I don't want to add library like jQuery and etc...**
- **I don't want to set p elements `style="pointer-events: none"`**
- **I want to use dynamic code (don't using e.target.parentElement)**

> Is it possible to detect parent elements clicking without giving event to it ( **with event bubbling** ) ?

> **The result code should work after client clicking on p element**

Comment: Thanks AlwaysHelping for answering but this doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: The result will worked when eventListener works after client clicked on p element...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the nesting of `.parent` is dynamic, you might want to determine the path from the [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to the [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). Then search through the path for the specific element you are looking for.

```js
// Determines the node path from baseNode to targetNode, by travelling up from
// the targetNode. The retuned array will include both the baseNode and the
// targetNode. If the targetNode is the baseNode an array with one elment is
// returned. Throws an error if baseNode is not an ancestor of targetNode.
function nodePath(baseNode, targetNode, currentPath = []) {
  currentPath.unshift(targetNode);
  if (targetNode == baseNode) return currentPath;
  return nodePath(baseNode, targetNode.parentNode, currentPath);
}

document
.querySelector(".container")
.addEventListener("click", ({currentTarget, target}) => {
  const path   = nodePath(currentTarget, target);
  const parent = path.find(node => node.matches(".parent"));

  if (parent) {
    console.log("It Worked!");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="parent">
     <!-- P Element Completely On Parent -->
     
     <p style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Hello</p>
   
     </div>
   ........
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering i forgot to use path, Thank you very much you solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could try this

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  
  var parentel = e.target.parentElement

  if (parentel.className == "parent") {

    alert(" It Worked!!! ")
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <!-- P Element Completely On Parent -->

    <p class- "child" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">Hello</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but i want to add event dynamic... This solution is static on parent